# R How to name a variable after a data.frame

Tags: r

I wish to use the name of a data frame to create a variable with it, via the function `signif`:

```
delta<-signif(((max(freq_1$Frequency) -min(freq_1$Frequency))/10), digits=1)
```

My data frame is freq with lots of frequencies in function of the time; with this function, I calculate the delta of the extreme frequencies.

But, since I have several dataframe of the kind `freq_i`, I want the term ''delta'' to actually be called automatically ''`delta_freq_i`'', in reference to the data frame it applies to.

Comment: Please show few lines of dataset and expected result

Comment: No, don't create objects called `x_1`, `x_2` etc etc. Make a `list` object which is a structure that can contain data frames in elements and then you can loop over that and create another list of whatevers. You can create objects via names and numbers via `get` and `assign` but its considered VERY bad practice.